# How do I get a hold of JsonSerializerSettings used in API controller methods

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, .net-core

In a controller I have something like this:

```
public IActionResult Foo() { return Content(new FooDto() { ... } }
```

The json returned from that controller method abides by some JsonSerializerSettings (e.g. it produces camelCased json).

In some other place in my code, I need to use `JsonConvert.Serialize(...)`, and I would like to use the same serializer settings as controller methods do. Is there some way I can get a hold of the JsonSerializerSettings used by controller methods?